# cannot convert from string to Uuid

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, c++14

I am trying to compile the following C++ code in Visual Studio 2017 C++ console application.

```
GUID patchId;
auto resa = UuidFromString("905EAA46-C9E3-4B5C-8133-0000165A4DDD", &patchId);
```

It gives me the following compilation error.

> Error    C2664    'RPC_STATUS UuidFromStringW(RPC_WSTR,UUID *)':
>   cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [37]' to 'RPC_WSTR'

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: fix: `L"905EAA46-C9E3-4B5C-8133-0000165A4DDD"`  it's expecting a wide string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be a bug in the system platform headers.  If you define `wchar_t` to be a distinct type from `unsigned short` (which you should), https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d1b4550a-407b-4c09-8560-0ab9ef6ff754/error-while-compiling-c2664?forum=vclanguage kicks in; `RPC_WSTR` is `unsigned short*` and should be `wchar_t*`.

Do this:

```
UuidFromStringW((RPC_WSTR)L"905EAA46-C9E3-4B5C-8133-0000165A4DDD", &patchId);
```

as horrible as that is.

Comment: I had tried both and still get the same error. Compiler also has following text. "Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast"

Comment: @BKS Aha, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d1b4550a-407b-4c09-8560-0ab9ef6ff754/error-while-compiling-c2664?forum=vclanguage

Comment: @BKS patched answer

Comment: Another option would be to call `UuidFromStringA` , avoiding the need for the hack